# Error Assigning Availability Set To Virtual Machine In Different Regions

Tags: virtual-machines, azure

Am I allowed to assign an availability set in East US 2 to a Azure VM in Central US.  I am getting this error below but the Availability set does exist in East US 2.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "NotFound",
    "message": "The Availability Set /subscriptions/resourceId/resourceGroups/Exposure/providers/Microsoft.Compute/availabilitySets/ExposureAvailabilitySet cannot be found."
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to be in an same availability set the VMs need to be in the same region.